# Does emacs limit the running threads up to 3?

Tags: multithreading, emacs

htop review the status of two running emacs servers as:

[image]

The number of executing threads is a constant of 3 and stay instant even though more buffers and  windows opened from a frame.

Does it limit the thread up to 3?

Comment: Wait a minute. Servers? Isn't emacs just a simple text editor? {pax ducks for cover} :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs is by and large single-threaded, so those 3 threads are most likely auxiliary threads used internally by Gtk, Glib, or some such library used by your Emacs build.

Comment: ty, could you please leave a reference about the single-threaded mechanism?

Comment: Indeed, I use the Lucid GUI and it creates one extra thread instead of three.

Answer (score 4):

You can create new threads via `make-thread`, eg.

```
(make-thread (lambda () (sit-for 20)) "sitting")
```

which should show something like

[image]

But as Stefan points out if you search the emacs codebase you won't find much thread creation outside of the implementation for lisp (eg. `Fmake_thread`).

Comment: Note that these thread mechanisms are very new (Emacs 26.1), and uses to date are largely experimental.  I suspect it will be a while longer before threads are niggle-free and start to find widespread application.